# Show multiple images specific X, Y, width and height in JavaScript canvas

Tags: javascript, html, json, canvas

I'm currently trying to make a canvas that shows a specific crop of an image. I have created a little piece of code that can do this with a single image, but I wonder if it is possible and how to use a json file that has multiple cropped images to show in a single canvas?

the code:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {

        clipImage(img, 140, 2, 120, 110);

    }
    img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    img.src = "image.jpg";

    function clipImage(image, clipX, clipY, clipWidth, clipHeight) {

        // draw the image to the canvas
        // clip from the [clipX,clipY] position of the source image
        // the clipped portion will be clipWidth x clipHeight
        ctx.drawImage(image, clipX, clipY, clipWidth, clipHeight,
        0, 0, clipWidth, clipHeight);
    }
</script>
```

example of the JSON:

```
[{"name":"image.jpg","clipWidth":512,"clipHeight":512, "clipX":0,"clipY":0},
{"name":"image2.jpg","clipWidth":512,"clipHeight":512, "clipX":30,"clipY":60}]
```

Comment: _"but I wonder if it is possible to use a json file that has multiple cropped images to show in a single canvas"_ - Yes. And the problem is? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @Andreas I'm new with JavaScript so I want to know how to do this or if there is any documentation/guide to do this.

Comment: Both not a topic for SO -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: while this question was simple and my answer took me less than 5 mins ... I do agree with @Andreas for your own benefit you have to put more research effort into these ... at the beginning it is painful and time consuming, but the research patience is a skill that will grow in you, and stay with you forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you got most of the way there...
Now it is just a loop over that json data, not sure how are you getting the data so as a quick example I'm using a textarea, see code below

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var field = document.getElementById("data");
var data = JSON.parse(field.value);

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    clipImage(img, data[i].clipX, data[i].clipY, data[i].clipWidth, data[i].clipHeight);
  }
  img.src = data[i].name;
}

function clipImage(image, clipX, clipY, clipWidth, clipHeight) {
  ctx.drawImage(image, clipX, clipY, clipWidth, clipHeight);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<br>
<textarea id="data" rows="9" cols="64">
[
{"name":"https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFBxY.png","clipWidth":70,"clipHeight":80, "clipX":0,"clipY":0},
{"name":"https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFBxY.png","clipWidth":89,"clipHeight":99, "clipX":70,"clipY":10},
{"name":"https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFBxY.png","clipWidth":50,"clipHeight":60, "clipX":170,"clipY":30}
]
</textarea>
```

Too keep the code short I removed all your comments and simplified your `ctx.drawImage` you should not have any problems changing all that to suit your needs

Comment: thank you very much this is what I was looking for!